# Images not referenced by solution explorer in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am using webcam to create images, i am saving that images in to the folder which belongs to another project. after saving the images its not reflecting in that folder, when i click show all files the images displays in the respective folder but its not rerenced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Projects (pre-ASP.NET 5, anyway) specify exactly which files are within them - Solution Explorer isn't a file-system explorer.

If you right-click on the folder and choose "Add... Existing Item" then you should be able to add the new images to the project. Of course, if this is something which is happening dynamically, you probably don't *want* the files within the project, and should probably pick them up in a different way. (We have no idea what you're trying to achieve, so it's hard to give specific advice on that front.)

Comment: Dynamically i add images to the folder.

Comment: @Ranjith: Right, so you shouldn't expect to see them in solution explorer. Beyond that, we can't suggest anything as we don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i have two projects in my solution. One is webcamproject.exe another one is auditproject. what i am doing is taking a image from webcam project and save it in to a audit project's folder to show the images for respective modules.

Comment: @Ranjith: Well it sounds like your audit project should pick up the files at execution time using `Directory.GetFiles` or something similar.

Comment: already doing the same but am confused that about images not referenced

Comment: @Ranjith: Why would you *need* them to be part of the project if you're already picking them up dynamically from the file system? Hint: look in the project file. See all the filenames listed? Those are the ones which show in Solution Explorer.